# pyspark intersection from two dataframes columns which are in list type

Tags: list, dataframe, join, pyspark, intersection

I have a dataframes with location columns and each cell contains list of country_name, I want to find the common country_name from both the columns and add it to a output dataframe.....coding in pyspark.....

```
df_input = spark.createDataFrame([
(100001,12301, 'India', ['India', 'USA','Germany']), (100002, 12302, 
'Germany', ['India', 'UK','Germany']), 
(100003,12303,'Taiwan',['India','Japan','China'])], ("pos_id","emp_id", 
"e_location", "p_location"))
```

Dataframe Input:

```
+------+------+----------+--------------------+
|pos_id|emp_id|e_location|          p_location|
+------+------+----------+--------------------+
|100001| 12301|     India|[India, USA, Germ...|
|100002| 12302|   Germany|[India, UK, Germany]|
|100003| 12303|    Taiwan|[India, Japan, Ch...|
+------+------+----------+--------------------+
```

Now I want the intersection between the two shown in Output DF.

Output Dataframe

```
+------+---------+----------------+
|emp_id|   pos_id| matched_country|
+------+---------+------+---------+
| 12301|   100001|           India|
| 12302|   100002|         Germany|
| 12303|   100003|            None|
+------+---------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume your `df_ploc` Dataframe contains a list of countries in the `p_location` column. Then you could use something like this to create the intersection and preserve all the combinations of `pos_id` and `emp_id`.

I modified the initial code snippet because of missing brackets and assumption of list (otherwise you have to include a `split` method.

```
df_ploc = spark.createDataFrame([
(000001, ['India', 'USA','Germany']), (000002, ['India', 'UK','Germany']), 
(000003,['India','Japan','China'])
], ("pos_id", "p_location"))

df_eloc = spark.createDataFrame([
(12301, 'India'), (12302, 'Germany'), (12303,'Taiwan')
], ("emp_id", "e_location"))

#create a new dataframe with one line per country
df_new = df_ploc.select("pos_id",explode("p_location").alias("new_location"))
df_eloc.join(df_new, df_new["new_location"] == df_eloc["e_location"], how="inner").show()
```

Output looks like:

```
+------+----------+------+------------+
|emp_id|e_location|pos_id|new_location|
+------+----------+------+------------+
| 12302|   Germany|     1|     Germany|
| 12302|   Germany|     2|     Germany|
| 12301|     India|     3|       India|
| 12301|     India|     1|       India|
| 12301|     India|     2|       India|
+------+----------+------+------------+
```

The modified Join could look like

```
df_eloc.join(df_new, df_new["new_location"] == df_eloc["e_location"], how="left").groupBy("emp_id","new_location").agg(min("pos_id")).show()
```

Which outputs something like:

```
+------+------------+-----------+
|emp_id|new_location|min(pos_id)|
+------+------------+-----------+
| 12301|       India|          1|
| 12302|     Germany|          1|
| 12303|        null|       null|
+------+------------+-----------+
```

If your pos_id should just be an enumeration (e.g. 1,2,3,4,5....) you can use some functions like `row_number` to create this column.
E.g.:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import monotonically_increasing_id
from pyspark.sql.functions import row_number
from pyspark.sql.window import Window as W

df1 = df_eloc.join(df_new, df_new["new_location"] == df_eloc["e_location"], how="left").groupBy("emp_id","new_location").agg(min("pos_id"))
df1 = df1.withColumn("idx", monotonically_increasing_id())
windowSpec = W.orderBy("idx")
df1.withColumn("pos_id", row_number().over(windowSpec)).select("emp_id","pos_id","new_location").show()
```

Output:

```
+------+------+------------+
|emp_id|pos_id|new_location|
+------+------+------------+
| 12301|     1|       India|
| 12302|     2|     Germany|
| 12303|     3|        null|
+------+------+------------+
```

Comment: Sorry I need the Intersection between the two columns - p_location & e_location.

The resultant column should contain - India, Germany, None
India coz e_loation has India and p_loction also contains India.
Similarly for Germany
But for None -- the country in e_location is different from the p_location lists.

So it throws blank/none.

I hope the result is bit clear - I cant upload pic for resultant output in comment

Comment: please see the question again I have added the output column (how it should look like)

Comment: It is not easily possible to get the correct pos_id values as in your result, because india is listed in pos_id 1,2 and 3 and germany in 1 and 2. So why it should use 2 for germany but 1 for india and also pos 3 for a None value does not make sense. 

But if you are mostly interested in the country values, you can modify the join like this:
df_eloc.join(df_new, df_new["new_location"] == df_eloc["e_location"], how="left").groupBy("emp_id","new_location").agg(min("pos_id")).show()

I will edit the answer